# И еще о ключах

Tags: омонимы

В продолжении темы о ключах. Почему родники тоже называют "ключами", а еще нечто очень важное и главное — "ключевым вопросом"?

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с предыдущими ответами, хочется уточнить. Омонимы Ключ1 и Ключ2 отличаются производящей основой.Ключ1-от клюка(палка с загнутым концом, кстати, ключица отсюда же), ей иногда отпирали замок (отмычка-та же клюка).
Ключ 2-от клюкать. Клюкать-от клюк-подражание звукам клю-клю, кот. издаёт вода при вытекании (наклюкался-напился).Потому и такая разница в смыслах.

Comment: Людмила, Фасмер допускает родство основ.

Comment: Клюка и клюкать? Вряд ли. Он говорит о так называемой народной этимологии, когда мы объясняем совпадения смыслов: ключ-ручей-тоже"открывает" реку. Это ненаучно - всего лишь совпадение, как и однажды один товарищ пытался доказать,что вода-от "водить", она же ведёт нас.Употребляться такое объяснение может только как метафора.

Comment: Нет. Фасмер не занимается "народной этимологией". 
//===  
Обычно сближается с клю́кать " шуметь" (см.); см. Бернекер 1, 529; Брюкнер 236, но имеет смысл поставить вопрос об одинаковом происхождении с ключ I.   
//===

Comment: Да помню я это его:"Ср. нем. выражение eine Quelle erschließen "открыть источник"." Никто из учёных его не поддержал, это только догадки.Вот именно "имеет смысл поставить вопрос"- ответа нет. Сейчас мы говорим о русских источниках слова, а не дальней индоевропейской связи смыслов.Это приведёт опять-таки к народной смысловой этимологии, как вдова-от "выдавать"-можно замуж выдавать- это же бред.Ключевой(важный)-от ключ-клюка, потому что"открывающий возможности овладения, управления чем-нибудь" и ещё от термина ключ-"верхний камень, замыкающий свод сооружения", т.е. без него объект не готов.

Answer (score 1):

Слово, совпадающее с другим словом по звучанию и написанию, но расходящееся по значению и системе форм (например: курс - направление движения корабля и курс - законченный цикл обучения; бар - маленький ресторан и бар - единица атмосферного давления; течь - литься, струиться и течь - пробоина), называется омоним (от греч. homos - одинаковый). Потому это слово такое многозначущее - *ключ к разгадке*, *скрипичный ключ*... и *ключ* - бьющий из земли источник, родник. 
А прил. *ключевой* образовано от сущ. *ключ*. И значения такие - главный, наиболее значительный в каком-л. отношении: ключевой вопрос, ключевые проблемы эконимики; открывающий возможности овладения чем-л., захвата чего-л.: ключевой пункт позиций, занять ключевые позиции.

Answer (score 0):

О ключе как роднике писал в предыдущем вопросе begemotus. Вот кусочек из его ответа: "ключ", др.-сакс. slutil – то же. II род. п. -а́ II. "источник, родник", болг. ключ (водата ври с ключ) "о шуме воды", сербохорв. кљу̑ч, род. п. кљу́ча "клокотание, бурление воды", кљу̀чати " кипеть, бурлить, клохтать". Обычно сближается с клю́кать " шуметь" (см.); см. Бернекер 1, 529; Брюкнер 236.
  Что касается "ключевого вопроса", то, думаю, это связано с тем, что с помощью такого "вопроса" можно "открыть" какую-либо проблему.